# How to forge a CBC-MAC

Tags: mac, forgery

I'm looking for a very clear explanation of how to forge a CBC-MAC. Given M1 = m1 and M2 = m1||m2 and M3 = m1|| m2 || m3$ and their respective MACs are MAC1 MAC2 and MAC3. How would I go about forging a valid MAC on a distinct message? Could I (for example) say (M4||M3 XOR MAC3)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC#Attack_methods

Comment: Is there anything unclear after reading [Having CBC-MAC of a one block message, forge CBC-MAC of two blocks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51866/555), or [Forge CBC-MAC given the MAC of two messages and of their concatenation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11538/555), or [Forge CBC-MAC by creating new message, giving the MAC of two messages](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/41662/555)? If so, edit the question to tell what you tried and did not work. Hint: [Google](https://google.com/search?q=forge+CBC-MAC+site:crypto.stackexchange.com) is good an indexing our website.